# How would we eliminate the need to use index.php after the domain name to visit the endpoints for October CMS with NGINX on shared hosting?

Tags: nginx, url, url-rewriting, shared-hosting

I am using October CMS with NGINX on a shared hosting plan. How do I go about removing the need to put `index.php` after the top-level domain.

For example: `http://www.example.com/index.php/backend/` should be `http://www.example.com/backend/`.

Thank you!

**The official documentation does not have a mention for shared hosting solutions.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I go about removing the need to put `index.php` after the top-level domain?

In this particular instance, it seems likely that this isn't possible.

> The official documentation does not have a mention for shared hosting solutions.

While you haven't provided a link to this documentation, these [official October CMS server configuration instructions](https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/configuration) seem to indicate that October CMS relies primarily on the web server to rewrite URLs.

Essentially, this means that on platforms where you do not have direct access to the web server configuration files, you are generally reliant on per-directory configuration files to define custom rules for URL rewriting. In the case of Apache, these are defined in `.htaccess` files. However, Nginx doesn't have any equivalent to these files that I am aware of.